# Permission to Google Cloud Storage via service account in Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I am trying to get a service account to create blobs in Google Cloud Storage
from within a Python script, but I am having issues with the credentials.

1) I create the service account for my project and then download the key file in json:

```
"home/user/.config/gcloud/service_admin.json"
```

2) I give the service account the necessary credentials (via gcloud in a subprocess)

```
 roles/viewer, roles/storage.admin,  roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator, roles/billing.user
```

Then I would like to access a bucket in GCS

```
from google.cloud import storage
import google.auth

credentials, project = google.auth.default()
client = storage.Client('myproject', credentials=credentials)
bucket = client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my_bucket?projection=noAcl:
s_account@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have
storage.buckets.get access to my_bucket
```

I have somewhat better luck if I set the environment variable

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="home/user/.config/gcloud/service_admin.json"
```

and rerun the script. However, I want it all to run in one single instance of the script that creates the accounts and continues to create the necessary files in the buckets. How can I access my_bucket if I know where my json credential file is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this example from the [Documentation for Server to Server Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_the_path_to_the_service_account_key_in_code):

```
from google.cloud import storage

# Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key file.
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')

# Make an authenticated API request
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)
```

This way you point the file containing the key of the Service Account directly in your code.

Comment: This works! Actually my error was that I was referring to a bucket [client.lookup_bucket('my_bucket') that was created in previous project and now deleted; hence the permissioning issue].